# catch mouse motion in gtkmm

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++11, gtk3, gtkmm3

I am trying to catch the mouse motion when I hold the mouse middle button. The goal is to implement a rotation feature in an stl viewer.

I found the event mask `BUTTON2_MOTION_MASK`. But I have a hard time figuring out which signal catches it.

Here's the two line I use to create and hook the event. These two line are inside a GtkApplicationWindow Constructor.

```
glWidget.add_events(Gdk::BUTTON2_MOTION_MASK);
glWidget.signal_motion_notify_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&mainWindow::rotate));
```

Here's the function I am trying to connect.

```
bool mainWindow::rotate(GdkEventMotion* motion_event)
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```

Am I using the correct method? The code does not react when I hold the middle mouse button and move mouse.

I managed to get glArea widget to react to scrolling this way.

```
glWidget.add_events(Gdk::SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK);

glWidget.signal_scroll_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&mainWindow::zoom));
```

the function I connected:

```
bool mainWindow::zoom(GdkEventScroll *eventScroll)
{
        cout<<"test"<<endl;
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping your glWidget inside a GtkEventBox.

Comment: Not sure if your glWidget has a GdkWindow to receive mouse events but if you wrap it around an EventBox you can receive them and GtkEventBox it's just a simple container. Lets say you have you actualContainer > glWidget, you just have to place it in the middle, actualContainer > EventBox > glWidget.

Comment: Hi @JoséFonte, sorry if I deleted my comment previously. My GLArea is inside a GtkApplicationWindow. I managed to get it to react to scrolling with the mouse button already. I know that the widget is at least able to react to `signal_scroll_event()`.

Comment: Ok, so try adding the event POINTER_MOTION_MASK . I've tried to recreate an example here but my machine is not able to get a GLContext so I can't check it

Comment: Hi, @JoséFonte. I tried to add POINTER_MOTION_MASK. Now everytime the cursor moves over the widget it catches the signal. Not quite, what I wanted since I only want it to catch the signal when a button is clicked. For you implementing an example, I don't think you it necessary for you to use a glwidget like me. any widget with the motion_notify_signal will do.

Comment: I feel like I am missing a detail here to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to both add the Gdk::Button1_MOTION_MASK and the Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK.

```
glWidget.add_events(Gdk::Button1_MOTION_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
```

This will catch the signal when the left mouse button is clicked and positioned on the widget.

BUTTON2_MOTION_MASK will require that 2 button are pressed. For some reason, it's only the left mouse button(I want the middle button).

Comment: I said "add" :) You needed both :) Search for Gtk Scribble example, it's similar but you draw instead of rotating something. Good luck.