# How can I get cursor position with Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, position, gtk, mouse, gtkmm3

Which Gtkmm functions can help me get the position(x,y) of the cursor. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727215/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-gtk-linux-monodevelop), C# has

> Gdk.Display.Default.WarpPointer(Gdk.Display.DefaultScreen, 20, 20);

Windows has

> [GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos)

Qt has

> [QCursor::pos()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523375/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-on-the-screen-in-qt)

Gtkmm has what?

Comment: Check out SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595045/catch-mouse-motion-in-gtkmm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [catch mouse motion in gtkmm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595045/catch-mouse-motion-in-gtkmm)

Comment: @ZF007 the duplicate you refer doesnt return an x and y coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Gtk::Main gtkm(argc, argv);
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Display> disp = Gdk::Display::get_default();
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> scrn = disp->get_default_screen();
    Gdk::ModifierType mods;
    int xpos, ypos;

    disp->get_pointer(scrn, xpos, ypos, mods);
    printf("xpos = %d, ypos = %d\n", xpos, ypos);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is now obsolete, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219089/516188) worked for me.

Comment: Who knows.. I guess there are people writing new code using old gtk versions still today?