# Query cursor position with GTK

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to query the cursor position using the GTK C libraries?  I am writing a program where I need to read out the position of the cursor in real time (either through a callback function or by polling the values to look for change). I have scanned through the GTK documentation, but I couldn't find anything obvious that exposes the cursor position.

I am currently writing this program using the GTK C libraries because a) I already have some code written in C to interface with the low level Raspberry Pi peripherals, and I'd rather not rewrite it for a different language if I can avoid it.  The low level code is based on mmap(), which I believe still works with C++, so if push comes to shove, I supposed I can rewrite it in C++ with some other GUI library like wxWidgets or QT.  (Are there easy ways to read the cursor position with those libraries?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at how it's done in those toy widgets which draw eyes on the panel, e.g. [xfce4-eyes-plugin](https://git.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-eyes-plugin/tree/panel-plugin/eyes.c?id=f74dce7ff5f61e507a85df803d218ed97ba3c52f#n165).

```
gboolean
where (void)
{
  gint x, y;
  GdkWindow *window;
  GdkDevice *mouse_device;

#if GTK_CHECK_VERSION (3,20,0)
  GdkSeat *seat = gdk_display_get_default_seat (gdk_display_get_default ());
  mouse_device = gdk_seat_get_pointer (seat);
#else
  GdkDeviceManager *devman = gdk_display_get_device_manager (gdk_display_get_default ());
  mouse_device = gdk_device_manager_get_client_pointer (devman);
#endif

  window = gdk_display_get_default_group (gdk_display_get_default ());
  gdk_window_get_device_position (window, mouse_device, &x, &y, NULL);
  g_message ("pointer: %i %i", x, y);

  return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE;
}
```

Comment: To get a valid display `gtk_init()`, `gtk_init_check()`, `gdk_init()`, or `gdk_init_check()` must have been called **beforehand**.